# Determine the causes of change in time with mixed models

Tags: r, time-series, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, time-varying-covariate

I have a database with several continuous variables measured in two times. I searched for a change in time in my dependent variables in this way:

`difJS<-lmer(JS~Time+(Time|id)+(Time|occupation),dat,REML=T)`

If I detect a significant fixed effect of Time I can say there is a change in time of JS (a confirm of this would be appreciated).
Now I would like to found what causes the change in time of my dependent variable but I did not found anything about how to do this or if it is possible and it seems very strange to me (my fault for sure).

Is it a right way to do as follow?

1. test for change in time of the covariates

`difCov<-lmer(Cov1~Time+(Time|id)+(Time|occupation),dat,REML=T)`

2. insert in the first model all the covariates with a significant change in time

`mod<-lmer(JS~Time+Cov1+Cov2+Cov3+Cov4+(Time|id)+(Time|occupation),dat,REML=T)`

3. to conclude that if Time became not significant the covariates in the model explain the change in time of the DV.

Is there a way to calculate the difference of the variance explained by Time in the first model and the one explained by Time in the model with the covariates? Or, better, is there a way to calculate how much variance that was explained by Time in the first model is explained by the covariates in the final model?
If in the model with the covariates the Time remains significant, as the covariates do, what can I conclude?